# Headless HTML5 performance capture as in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

I've recently been working with Chrome's dev tools Performance tab to reduce the processing burdens of my page. I'm hoping to be able to append a check into my CI so that this isn't an exclusively manual process going forward.

Captures provide the following information:

[image: Performance Summary image]

This gives me the amount of time spent idle, and I know how long I've run the test for, so I can get %idle. I'd like to be able to run a headless process evaluating the page that ultimately allows me to determine %idle in the same way.

Is there a tool that can do this? I'd be happy to go as far as installing a headless chrome browser if there's a way to get this information in a report generated using command line arguments maybe?